# JSON response a javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, object, extjs

I'm using EXTJS with JSON. I'm trying to return an object in the json response but it is not working. I have the following:

```
{"success": true,
    "results" : [ {
        "type":{
            "title":"example"
        }
    },{
        "type":{
            "subtitle":"example"
        }
    }
]}
```

In firebug it outputs this:

```
type   "[object Object]"
```

Is this because of the data model? I'm not sure what type to use for type.

Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to access this object?

Comment: `Object.toString()` returns `"[object Object]"` by default. Use a better debugging method. How about `console.log('type', foo)` instead of `console.log('type ' + foo)`?

Comment: @Cerbrus Are you trying to serialize object and return string as a result, or just pass an object? It's not completely clear from your question what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am really not sure what you are trying to do. Maybe create a js fiddle so we have a better idea of what you are doing.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, sorry about that. :)

Comment: The JSON is returning an Object and I need to use that object later. Right now I'm only trying to console.log the object to see if the correct detail is there.

Comment: Never mind, stupid me. I had a converter which I forgot to remove. Sorry about that, it's working fine now. Thanks for all the help guys

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling this with the Ext JS `Ext.Ajax.request`?  You could do something like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'your_url',
    success: function (response) {
        var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

`obj` should now contain the content you're sending in the response. `Ext.decode` is the Ext method that will convert a JSON string into its corresponding javascript object.